# Compile node.js module to a single file

Tags: javascript, node.js

After using npm to install module
`npm install discord.js`
a folder with name `discord.js` was created but I want to compile this node module to a single javascript file and use it in my project `require("./discord.js");`.

Comment: What about using a module bundler? You can require the files you need in a single file and bundle their content into a single file using a module bundler (webpack, rollup, parcel...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use the `webpack` builds of discord.js, available [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/tree/webpack). Note that there are some [restrictions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/topics/web) when using these files. (you can also compile the files yourself using another tool so everything will work).